# what does "is off by" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

what does "is off by" mean in this sentence?

> If the height of a single step
>   **is off by** as little as two millimeters...

Comment: **off** means **inaccurate** (as with a measurement) or **not conforming to dimensional specifications** (as with a manufactured object).

Answer (score 7):

***| be off by| means to be less or more than what a measurement should be***. Any measurement: time, distance, height, width, weight, etc.

The wall measures 6 feet 2 inches, so the wallpaper has to measure the same thing.
If the wallpaper is only 6 feet, it is ***off by 2 inches***.

The man ran a mile in five minutes. [less]
You're off by three. [in other words you ran it in eight]. [more]

Your ideal weight as a man should be 85 kilos for your height.
But you only weigh 80 kilos. You are off by five. [less]

The time is 6 o'clock according to your watch.
Mine is off by two  hours. [Context will tell if it is supposed to 8 or 4 o'clock.] [travel and time zones]

Comment: What's the opposite of "off by" in this context?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu There is no opposite of "to be off by x" in this context. The idea of off relates to a measurement of some kind (time, distance, weight, etc.) and can be more than or less than some amount depending on the context. Only context will tell which it is.

Comment: I got it, sir. Thank you.

Comment: @Kumarsadhu Thank you for your question. I'm a woman but there's no need to say Ma'am. :)

Comment: "Prices are fifty percent off." can it mean both-- increase and decrease in price?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu It depends on your "standard". It does not mean an increase/decrease ***per se***. If your standard rate is 1,000 rupees per widget, then 1,250 or 750  would be off by 250, up or down. If the standard time for a machine cycle is 25 minutes, and it only runs 20 minutes or 30 minutes, it is off by 5 minutes. The amount something is off, up or down, is in relation to some standard measurement implied or given in a context.

Answer (score 3):

"is off by" means "is wrong or inconsistent by this amount". We normally expect stairs to all be the same size. If you are walking up a flight of stairs and one is a little different from the others, this can be very disconcerting. So they're saying that one step is a slightly different height than other steps.

We routinely talk about a measurement being "off by" some amount. Like, "When you set the flux on the hyperdrive, if you're off by more than 5% the engines may explode."